# Magento2 - Error: Can't find custom block

Tags: magento2, module, custom-block

I've created my custom extension and tried to install it. Now I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'My\Module\Block\Customer\Form\Register'
>   not found in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 117, referer: http://192.168.56.101/magento2/

I tried to recompile the di, upgrade with setup command, clean cache, but nothing works.

How can I fix it?

Comment: you clear the generation folder in var?

Comment: Yes. I recompiled di and the generation folder was regenerated but it doesn't work.

Comment: you checked that your block file is exists My\Module\Block\Customer\Form\Register

Comment: Yes. The curious thing is that it is working correctly on my Win Xampp installation. After trying on my new CentOS dev environment it doesn't work. I think it could correlate with the permissions...

Comment: Make sure you have the case correct. I.e. Register, not register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make sure you have the case correct. I.e. Register, not register. –
>   Smartie

Thanks Smartie the issue was the wrong case for my module. I created folders with lower case and used upper case in code. ;-)